# Save all Google presentation slides as images

Tags: images, google-slides

I have a Google presentation with many slides. I tried *File* → *Download As* → SVG or PNG, but only the first slide was converted. Is there a way to automatically convert all slides to images?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add an answer here. However, adding this comment in case anyone coming here is using MAC. In that case, you may download Keynote, then after downloading your Google slides presentation as a ppt, open it in Keynote then export all slides as images.

Comment: @philippos I thought anyone can post an answer, but you need at least (50?) rep to post a comment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have access to MS PowerPoint, one option is to save the Docs presentation as a .ppt, and then use the Save As option from PowerPoint which does have "all slides" option.

Comment: That's just what I actually did

Comment: There is now an online tool by Adobe https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-jpg.html

Answer (score 17):

1. Install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (great open source software)
2. Save your presentation to pdf: File > Download as... > PDF Document (.pdf)
3. Convert the pdf to multiple png files using ImageMagick's `convert` command:

   ```
   convert your_presentation.pdf your_slide_%03d.png
   ```

**Done! :)**

This will create one png file per slide, named `your_slide_000.png`, `your_slide_001.png`, etc.

If you would like a higher resolution image, just set the `-density` option. For example, for 300 dpi images:

```
    convert -density 300 your_presentation.pdf your_slide_%03d.png
```

The `convert` command has many other options you can explore (see [the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)). For example, the `-trim +repage` options crop the images to remove the empty space around your content:

```
    convert -density 300 -trim +repage your_presentation.pdf your_slide_%03d.png
```

**Note**: I had trouble with `-trim` because for some reason my slide's borders were sometimes white and sometimes transparent. I worked around this issue by making my slides' background transparent in Google Presentation (select all slides, click the "Background..." button, set the color to Transparent). Then my png files were properly trimmed and their background was transparent. If you don't want a transparent background in your png files, you can add `-background '#ff0000' -alpha remove` just after the `-trim +repage` option. This will make the background bright red, just replace the color (`#ff0000`) to any color you like. Another option is to first remove transparency as above, then trim. It works too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: for pdfs and imagemagick, you'll also need ghostscript: https://superuser.com/a/851168/167761

Comment: Might need to [change your ImageMagick configuration to allow extracting images from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion/53180170#53180170).

Answer (score 7):

No need to download any additional software if you have Adobe Acrobat, simply...

1. Save your presentation to pdf: File > Download as > PDF Document (.pdf)
2. Open the PDF in Acrobat and then: File > Export To > Image > (Choose prefered file format)

It will automatically start creating each slide as its own image inside the directory you have the PDF saved in.

Comment: According to an anonymous commentator, "Acrobat no longer allows save as image", please check.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, one at a time is best, as the conversion to PowerPoint re-positions elements. Don't get a surprise!

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> → <kbd>D</kbd> (*File* → **Download**) will make it go a little faster!

Comment: 8 years later it looks like this combo doesn't work anymore. But Alt+Shift+F → D → N does, and then `Esc →down` to go to the next slide and repeat. Unfortunately it's not very fast

Answer (score 1):

I am very unsure whether I am allowed to give a programming-related answer on this website. I'll just give you my code anyways since this is a fast way to do it (for those who do not have Microsoft Powerpoint).

1. Download [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) extension for FireFox.
2. Go to your Google Slide.
3. Open iMacros and on the menu just press `Record` then press `Stop` immediately.
4. Right click `#Current.iim` and click Edit.
5. Copy and paste the following code.

   ```
   ' This is the code for downloading lots of slides.
   ' The delay is just in case Firefox is too slow to keep up
   WAIT SECONDS=0.2
   ' These lines are where it goes to file -> download -> PNG
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#docs-file-menu" BUTTON=0
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\:7r>DIV>SPAN" BUTTON=0
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\:2dm>DIV>SPAN" BUTTON=0
   WAIT SECONDS=0.2
   ' This is the menu command for telling the script to go to next slide.
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#punch-slide-menu" BUTTON=0
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\:9p>DIV" BUTTON=0
   WAIT SECONDS=0.2
   ' end of macro loop
   ```
6. After you have copied and pasted the code, save the macro.
7. Now manually download the first slide because that way anything you download onwards will now give it a file-name followed by a number with `()` brackets between. It helps for labeling the slide number on each file.
8. Select a slide (preferably the first slide).
9. Just right above the `Play (Loop)` button you will see a max number to set it at. Set it at whatever you want (the total number of slides in your presentation).
10. Run the script.

Notes: This script is designed to download each slide from the beginning of the powerpoint. You must configure Firefox to automatically select a destination for download (or else the prompt box interferes with the script).

Comment: Why can't I format code on this site lol?

Comment: Because the code is embedded in a list, you need to indent it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Did some googling. If you want a no software, no site solution, looks like everyone is recommending Export as PDF, then run Automator script. Couple of options.

1. Use this automator script to get each page as an image - https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/quick-tip-how-to-save-all-pdf-pages-as-images/
2. Create your own automator script - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3311405
3. Use these settings - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3311405

An easier way is to use the site https://pdf2png.com/

Upload your PDF. Let it process. Download a zip containing all your images. Took a while but it worked well.

I thought for sure Acrobat would have a way. But the only export options are Microsoft Word and Powerpoint and Rich Text.

[image]

Seems crazy that there is not an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As you experienced, the native tool in Google to "Download as PNG image" will only export the "current slide" which you have selected.

I had the exact same question as you and found a free [Mac App](http://mymixapps.com/recasto) to help me export an entire Google slide presentation as individual images (PNG, JPG, BMP, or TIFF). It packages all the image files, for each slide, into one single folder. I also found a free [PC tool](http://www.freepdfsolutions.com/free-pdf-to-png-converter.html) that claims to do the same but I could not test it to confirm.

With the Mac app, do the following:

1. In Google slides: File > Download as... > PDF Document
2. Download the respective PC or Mac app mentioned above
3. Drag & Drop your PDF into the app interface, then click "Next Step"
4. You can adjust the DPI if you want higher quality slides
5. Click the image type to export as, and select a location

That's it!

As others have stated, you don't want to export as a PowerPoint, as your slide elements will likely shift. Exporting as PDF, **and then** using a PDF to IMG type of converter will ensure you get the highest quality of Google Presentation slides as images.

Answer (score -3):

From what I’ve found using Google Slides: if you click *File* then *Download as PNG*, they’ll download it as a photo. But you’ll have to do this for each slide.